# Calling PHP classes from a URL

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm using a class called `Group_Attributes()` in my project. I have it placed in my project and I call it the usual way.

```
$gt = new Group_Attributes();
```

This class is also accessible as text on `http://myurl.com/files/Group_Attributes.php` which outputs the class as text.

I'm thinking to call this class directly from there without without saving this file directly to my project.

Are there any disadvantages to doing something like this, especially if the number of files grows to 100 or more

Comment: I don't understand.  What do you mean by "call this class directly from there without without saving this file directly to my project"?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please be more specific.

Comment: @eml he wants to include files that are on another site; basically include via fopen.

Comment: @Obsidian_ then what does "especially if the number of files grows to 100 or more" mean?

Comment: @eml likely wants to include a ton of files (possibly even an entire library) this way

Comment: @Obsidian: Ah yes, that sounds like a likely interpretation.

Comment: @sameold we really need clarification on what you're intending to do here.  are you trying to include files that are stored on another site, or include files on the same server but located in a different directory, or...?

Comment: You want to execute code that is on a different server? That is a really bad idea. Why do you want to do that? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Very vague question, please show the code of your class>?

Comment: @stefgosselin, The code of the classes is irrelevant. You're missing the question entirely. @Obsidian_ got it.

Comment: @sameold  - How can _just_ a class output text in a browser? I understand it is probably a security risk in action but would of liked to have a peek at the code. Although Obsidians answer _probably_ fits, he did go on the general assumption that executing code remotely is bad, without seeing the code.

Comment: @stefgosselin "how can just a class output text in a browser" - ever had the PHP handler not kick in on your webserver daemon, and it's just serving the php code as-is without running it by the PHP parser? I think that's what he's referring to, just including the source code to run from a remote location.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like an invitation to man-in-the-middle RFI attacks.  Unless you're absolutely sure that the file you're including is completely, totally, 100% safe and that the transmission hasn't been hijacked, you are better off with it on your local filesystem.  Otherwise, all it takes is a poisoned DNS entry and suddenly you're executing some completely foreign and likely unsafe code on your system.

Also, having to fetch those files over and over again will slow down site load when you have several includes that way.

My answer?

*NO, AVOID AT ALL COSTS.*

Comment: +1: If your assumption about what the OP is asking is correct, then this is a good answer.

Comment: I'm afraid that's what it is.  I hope it isn't, because it's a very dangerous tactic to try.

Comment: Are you sure this is what is being asked? It sounds to me like he just wants to autoload a local class based on the URL the user visits.

Comment: @Dave: "I'm thinking to call this class directly from there without without saving this file directly to my project." -- the bit about "saving the file directly to my project" is what I am keying in on and has me believing that.

Comment: @Obsidian_, **(1)** OK, what if the other file is completely under my control? **(2)** By this logic, it's not safe to download anything that you haven't written yourself, even a library in zip format, because I may be downloading a library in zip, but the DNS entry has been poisoned so it's the same story. +1 Good answer by the way.

Comment: Another question is how do I ensure that "the transmission hasn't been hijacked"?

Comment: @sameold encryption or verifiable signing. If you've ever used a linux desktop system and had to add external repos, you'll notice that you have to add their package signing keys as well. This is so you can verify that the code is authentic and from who it is supposed to be. There's something that you *can* use for this purpose, but it requires PHP 5.3 + OpenSSL, or PHP 5.2 + OpenSSL + PHAR installed via PECL.  https://github.com/koto/phar-util - look at "Secure remote code deployment with PharUtil" in the readme

Comment: @sameold while you're technically right, unless you're handed the code physically you can't be sure who it came from and if it's safe, it doesn't mean that you should hand yourself to an attacker on a silver platter.  I hope you take the above links and run with it if you're looking at secure remote includes, it should give you a massive advantage over any attackers so long as you keep your private signing key, well, private.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate answer, if you're looking to load a local class instead of a hard file based on the URL the user visits, you should know that this is typically a technique that most PHP frameworks utilize and you may save a lot of time by instead implementing a framework.

Check out the URL Routing guide for Kohana at http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/routing - if you have 100s of potential files, you can utilize routing techniques to make a certain URI structure follow a `class/method/param` type setup.